# CDHTMLDialog : Notification not received when HTML loaded via Frameset tags

Tags: mfc

I am using CDHTMLDialog from MFC to get Click notifications from HTML Element in Web pages.  However I am not getting any notification, if the Webpage has Frameset Tags.  Please let me know the steps on how to get notifications.

Thanks,
Edwin.

Answer (score 0):

The MFC DHTML event macros are not designed for elements inside frames. The MFC implementation only look for elements in the top level document.

Hook up the event sink manually with the MFC source as a reference. See [Handling HTML Element Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508508%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [How to get the WebBrowser object model of an HTML frame](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196340)

Comment: Thank you Sheng Jiang.  I tried that approach and couldn't move an inch.  So I choose the CDHTMLDialog based on one of the samples provided by Mircosoft SDK.  I tried writing code based on the approach you had suggested, but it did not work at all.  I would be glad to have a sample which works, as I am new (6 months) to C++ programming ?? Thanks,Edwin

Comment: Override CDHtmlDialog::OnDocumentComplete, enumerate frames based on KB196340 (replace m_webBrowser.GetDocument with CDHtmlDialog::GetDHtmlDocument), skip all other frames except the frame you are interested in, then enumerate elements or call GetElementById to find the element in the frame, use AtlAdvise to hook up your own CDHtmlElementEventSink-like event handler to the element. Unadvise event handlers in OnBeforeNavigate.